# How to read results from a shapefile using readOGR from the rgdal package in R?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sp, rgdal

So I read my shapefile easily:

```
shape<-readOGR(".","shapefile")
```

then if I do head(shape,1) I get the following result:

```
An object of class "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
Slot "data":
  ID NAME PROJECT       UP      DOWN
0  1   X    05076     110468    38282
Slot "lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Lines"
Slot "Lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Line"
Slot "coords":
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1824583 547917.9
[2,] 1824544 547437.1

Slot "ID":
[1] "0"

Slot "bbox":
        min       max
x 1824543.9 1824583.4
y  547437.1  547917.9

Slot "proj4string":
CRS arguments: NA
```

So getting the data is easy, I just do shape$NAME and I get all the names from the data.

But I don't know how to access the place where it says Slot "coords" which is what I want to access... or for that matter, how do I access things that are not on the data slot?

In other words, i want to read the shapefile and end up with a variable equal to 1824583, which is the top left value of the coords slot matrix.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `@` to access the slots. Here I used the `meuse` dataset as an example.

```
library(sp)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

head(meuse@coords)
#        x      y
# 1 181072 333611
# 2 181025 333558
# 3 181165 333537
# 4 181298 333484
# 5 181307 333330
# 6 181390 333260

meuse@coords[1, 1]
# [1] 181072
```